# Java close FileInputStream before reading anything

Tags: java, android, serial-port, fileinputstream

I have a very peculiar problem. In android I am using FileInputStream to read from the serial (ttySx/COM) port. I am using this to decide which of the known devices is connected (if any at all). What I basically do is:

1. Are you device 1? No...
2. Are you device 2? No...
3. Are you device 3? Yes...
4. Great lets do some stuff...

And this works great. If there is any incoming data to read (response from device), everything is fine. However, if there is no device connected to ttySx there is nothing to respond to my write. That means nothing to read.

Now, *FileInputStream.read()* is a blocking call. When I call it in the thread, thread is effectively frozen. I cannot interrupt the thread because for that I would have to read something first. So far everything makes perfect sense.

As there is no response from the port for quite some time I decide that there is nothing connected and want to stop reading and dispose of the thread(actually I do not want to bother with the port anymore because with nothing connected, it is useless to me at this moment). As mentioned earlier interrupt itself is no good. What should be working, is to *close()* the FileInputStream (*read()* will throw an exception and hooray!). The *close()* works... As long as the *read()* read anything ever (like when I had an answering device connected, then disconnect it -> *read()* is stuck - because no data to read - but *close()* works).

**However if there was not a thing connected to the port when the *read()* started (equals: I haven't read a single byte), the *close()* method does nothing. It does not close the stream. Nor does work the closing of FileInputStream channel.**

I could create a workarround: Store the FileInputStream somewhere and when I want to read from the port again later, use the same instance. That would work for me. Unfortunately I would quite unnecessarily block the port itself. No other process (for example another application) could read from the port because it is stuck in "uninterruptable" read...

Any ideas why this is happening and how to make it right? Or some other way to detect if there is anything connected to the ttySx port?

Thanks.

EDIT1: The library used for communication with serial port is https://github.com/cepr/android-serialport-api

Comment: Have you tried if `InputStream::available()` method is any good for you? I'm not particularly sure if it'll work in your case, but maybe it's worth a try. Also, is there really no way to interrupt a `read()` call? What if you tried to wrap in `Future` or something along these lines (that would be my first instinct)?

Comment: Another question: have you tried the same case without using FileInputStream at all? Interrupt requirement is a thing in `java.nio`, maybe reading from FileChannel will work better for this?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: thanks. Yes, I did try `InputStream::available() `. It returns 0 every time. Even when there is anything to read. Therefore totaly unreliable. As for the FileChannel -> interesting idea. I will try it out.

Comment: Why aren't you using a library that handles the serial port communications for you?  While you can technically use a `FileInputStream`, there are other settings to be concerned about(baud rate, stop bits, etc)

Comment: @rm5248: actually, as far as I know, there is some third party library used (I am not the one that was implementing it, and won't be able to have a look at the sources for a few days now, therefore I can't tell which library exactly it is). This FileInputStream thing is "under the hood" behavior of that library. Do you have any experience with rs232 communication on android and suggest a specific library? I would be most grateful and gladly switch it for the old one :-).

Comment: I don't know anything about Android specifically - I've only done serial ports on non-Android Linux and Windows.  I would recommend making sure that you are running an actual library for serial ports.  Java serial port libraries: [RXTX](http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), [PureJavaComm](http://www.sparetimelabs.com/purejavacomm/purejavacomm.php), [JSSC](https://github.com/scream3r/java-simple-serial-connector), [JavaSerial](https://github.com/rm5248/JavaSerial)(mine).

Comment: @rm5248: I edited the question and added the used library. I also had a look at the libraries you suggested. Unfortunately I lack enough examples on android. Most are missing or require to root the android device which is not acceptable. I have to admit, though, that my search was not very thorough and I lack the resources to start experimenting with them. I had a look at your library as well. I see you mention Input/Output streams too, but I guess you haven't experienced "my" behavior. At the moment, I am wondering if switching to `BufferedReader` will yield different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we used `FileInputStream::available()`.

First time we tried it, it was like:

1. Check if anything is available.
2. Read (regardless of availability)

Of course, when we checked the *available*, there was nothing to read yet. Then the *read* call blocked and waited for input. When we checked again, there was nothing *available* already, because *read* had cleared the port.

Therefore this suggestion [Java close FileInputStream before reading anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43122914/java-close-fileinputstream-before-reading-anything?noredirect=1#comment73325586_43122914) from M. Prokhorov was the correct one for my situation.

---

If anyone would wonder about the behavior in question: 
From researching it, it seems that reading streams was not designed for ports/sockets in first place. It was designed for regular files. You read, reach the end of document and close the stream. The exceptions are designed for wrong sequential usage of a stream (you open it, close id and then try to read). 
If you enter blocking mode, it will block until it reads at least a byte. No way around it. *Close* initializes the "closing state" similarly to setting the interrupt state of a thread.